# Creating author profiles with extra fields and exporting that data?

Tags: custom-field, author

I'm trying to find a way to let my subscribers sign up to my site and enter details in their author pages to confirm their attendance at an event. In order to create the additional fields, I've been following this excellent tutorial by Justin Tadlock:

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

However, I need a way to export that information - is there a plugin that would let me do that? Or a useful resource for building something that would let me export that info as a csv file?

Thanks for any pointers,

Osu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-users/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-users/%20%22wordpress%20user%20list%20and%20csv%20plugin) (also has details at http://wpusersplugin.com/)  allows one to define the data in a user list  and then export to csv that list.

Comment: That's great, looks like it will do the job. Thanks fo the link!